# How to remove grey borders on the submit button?

Tags: html, css

so I'm styling a button and I can't seem to figure out how to override some of it's default stylings

this is my styled button

[image]

there is an odd border just below the word submit the one that's colored grey

this is my desired output:

[image]

how do you override that grey border thing?

Comment: Just guessing without seeing the code try `outline:0;`

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try removing the border with: `border-style: none;` and adding `outline-style: none;` in your css style.

Something like this:

```css
button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4183D7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: #38549D 0 5px 0 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline-style: none;
  padding: 18px 60px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: it's actually the border style that does it. thank you very much.

I didn't know the default properties to override for the submit button

Answer (score 1):

Try to add : `outline: none` for the style of the element of the button.
You have to check the displaying for the browsers because it's looking different...